# Knockout click binding fires after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a knockout binding that scrolls to a part if the page on click with this function

```
scrollTo() {
    $("a.scroll").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

The html where i call the function

```
<a class="scroll icon-arrow-down" href="#part" data-bind="localizedText: { id: '4-anchor-1', html: true }, tap: controller.scrollTo.bind(controller)"></a>
```

The problem is that it fires after the second click and not the first. Also this happen when coming on the page when you click a button it does not fire click it again it fires and then it function normally on other button to.

Comment: When do you call `scrollTo()`?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because on the first click you call `scrollTo()` which binds the event. Then on the next and each successive click you add another `click()` handler as well as execute all previous `click` event handlers. You just need to remove the `scrollTo()` function and add the event on load:

```html
<a class="scroll icon-arrow-down" href="#part" data-bind="localizedText: { id: '4-anchor-1', html: true }"></a>
```

```js
$("a.scroll").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Alternatively, if the `a` element is appended to the DOM dynamically you would need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', "a.scroll", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: When I do this it actually changes the url and refreshes the page I want to prevent this.

Comment: The `event.preventDefault()` should stop that behaviour. You may have an error in the JS which is stopping that from working, check the console for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Knockout, don't use the jQuery event bindings. Assuming you have defined a `tap` binding handler (which is to say, to call an event handler like `click` does), your HTML markup is fine. Just turn your `scrollTo` method into an event handler.

```
scrollTo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 500);
}
```